# How to emulate MixRGB (Mix) with math node for Grayscale?

Tags: materials, node-editor, mathematics, procedural

I would like to do a little research, and I would like to simulate a MixRgb type node with a mathematical node, to mix BW type maps, since the MixRGB mixes 3 channels, it would be enough for me to mix only one (0-1 Bw), but I'm not sure how to test this with math, I tried the Math node "Multiply Add"
I was curious to compare the performance between the RGB type and a node built with single value math, I did not find much about it by looking on the internet
Example:
(I would like to try to emulate, to compare the performances)

[image]

Comment: Is using a vector-math node acceptable for what you're trying to do?

Comment: I was trying to avoid using a 3 channel way, like RGB or XYZ (which seem the same thing after all)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This 'Mix Value' node group will emulate the simple Mix of two values:

[image]

- The inputs are all clamped 0-1
- The result is `[(1-Fac) * Value 1] + [Fac * Value 2]`

You can use this framework to test it:

[image]

The outputs of the *Mix RGB* node and of the combined lower branches, mixing the channels independently, are indistinguishable.

If you want to test the other mix modes, [this reference](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-concepts-layer-modes.html) could be handy.You would replace the 'Add' in the node group with the functions described. here's a link to the Blender code, [thanks to this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/183399/35559) by @Meng Hui Tan.

Have fun!

[image]

Comment: Oops , I left a crazy Fac value in the input node after testing.. I was making sure noithing went out of range in the result..

Comment: Very interesting, I am doing tests to understand the consumption of resources in comparison with the mixrgb node as regards only black and white, therefore single-value maps. But I don't understand if there is a difference in performance. We should try on big scenes

Comment: I don't know.. I _suspect_ not much difference, since in all the renderer's heavy-lifting areas, the contribution of rays will be evaluated in full RGB? I don't think the renderers can be forced into a monochrome mode.. i think the single channel can only be obtained by extraction from a full-color render. maybe someone who knows will come along.

Comment: Your reasoning seems correct, I look forward to someone who may be able to explain the situation better. Your answer enlightened me

Comment: @RobinBetts
Hi, Mr. Robin Betts,
I've been using the function in your answer for a while now, but I've just learnt that it's called ''Linear Interpolation Function''. 
Function is: (1-x)*a+x*b . 
You can see more of it right here: https://youtu.be/NO5JGFJJ_Kk?t=137 
I don't want to bother you, just want to share an interesting fact :)

Comment: Hi @Ian!   .. or `lerp` for short, if you ever wind up wanting it in, say, GLSL. Strangely, I've just this minute finished putting another one together for myself for Geometry Nodes.. I think I could have just downloaded my own old answer :D