# The difference between Factor and Image: How can I combine them?

Tags: node-editor, edit-mode, image

I do not understand [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/color/mix.html) what is the difference between **Fact** and **Image**:

> ### **Inputs**
>
> **Factor**
>
> Controls the amount of influence the node exerts on the output image.
>
> **Image**
>
> The background image. The image size and resolution sets the dimensions of the output image.

How can I combine those two: **Image** and **Fact** ?

Comment: The easiest way is to try :) Instead of images you can set two colors in each socket and try what happens if you slide Factor or plug another black/white image into this socket. Seems to me self explanatory. The only attention is good to have on mind - top socket is for bottom image, second socket is for top image (and not like in other apps in oposite order)

Comment: There's a breakdown of what Fac does [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/182510/35559)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont combine Image and Factor.
You combine two images and Factor says how to blend these two images.

Color 1 (red) is background (BG)
Color 2 (blue) is like in foreground (FG)

Factor 0 = 0% of FG (second socket)
Factor 0.5 = 50% of FG and BG (equaly mixed)
Factor 1 = 100% of FG

[image]

As factor can be used also 3D textures or black-white image.

[image]

---

*Note:*
*The order of items is one of Blender speciality :) logic comes from coding (I guess) from typing commands. Like first you order:*
*- paint red and then*
*- paint blue on top of red*

*... so sockets looks like these two rows. Other apps ussually use visual order - items for BG are lower, items of foreground on top.*

Answer (score 5):

It is easier to understand if you use a black and white image to combine the elements.

This black and white image has two values: 0 means Black, and 1 means White.

[image]

The Factor input determines how two other elements in a node are combined:

Whatever is black will be the color of the Top image socket,

Whatever is white will be the image connected to the Bottom socket.

[image]

All other values between 0 and 1 (different tones of gray) in the Factor image, will result in a mix between the two values.

[image]